# How to send smtp email from Command using Swiftmailer with Symfony

Tags: symfony, smtp, symfony4, swiftmailer

I have a problem sending my emails with Symfony.

swiftmailer.yaml

```
swiftmailer: 
  default_mailer: gmail_api 
  mailers: 
   gmail_api: 
     transport: gmail_api
```

As you can see I'm not using the spooling.

My emails are sent correctly from Controller but not from Command.

From Controller, *send()* return 1 and I receive the email.

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;

class CRUDController extends Controller
{

private $mailer;
...

public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
    ...
}

private function sendEmail($object, $identifiant, $type)
{
    $message = (new \Swift_Message('xxx ' . $identifiant))
                ->setFrom('xxx@xxx.xx')
                ->setTo('xxx@xxx.xx')
                ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView(
                        ...
                    ),
                    'text/html'
                )
                ->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath('xxx');
    try {
        $logger = new \Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger();
        $this->mailer->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));

        $numSent = $this->mailer->send($message);

        if ($numSent < 1) {
            $this->addFlash('sonata_flash_error', 'Fail to send e-mail');
        } else {
            if (method_exists($object, 'getMailing')
                && method_exists($object, 'setMailing')) {
                $object->setMailing($object->getMailing() + 1);
                $this->em->persist($object);
                $this->em->flush();
            }
        }
    } catch (\Swift_TransportException $e) {
        $this->addFlash('sonata_flash_error', $e->getMessage());
    }
    dump($logger->dump());
    exit();
}
```

\Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger give me:

> ++ Starting Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport 
>   ... 
>   << 250 OK

From Command, send() return 0 and I don't receive the email.

```
class ExempleCommand extends Command
{
    private $mailer;
    ...   

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        ...
    }



    protected function sendNotificationMail(OutputInterface $output, $subject, $body)
    {
        $logger = new \Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger();
        $this->mailer->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));

        $message = (new \Swift_Message($subject))
            ->setFrom('xxx@xxx.xx')
            ->setTo('xxx@xxx.xx')
            ->setBody(
                $this->twig->render(
                ...
                ),
                'text/html'
            );
        try {
            $output->write("\n" . $this->mailer->send($message));
        } catch (\Swift_TransportException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        $output->write($logger->dump());
    }
```

\Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger give me:

> ++ Starting App\Service\Email\GmailApiTransport
>   ++ App\Service\Email\GmailApiTransport started

Why it's not starting with Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport within Command?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how it work with Symfony 4, never had to send mail via command since a while but on Symfony 2, when using a command you had to start a new instance of the mailer. So maybe you can try to change your constructor to

```
public function __construct(\Swift_SmtpTransport $transport)
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);
}
```

(Sorry, i don't have the privilege to simply put a comment yet)

Comment: Sorry for the false lead.